# AI car development for computer player

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, artificial-intelligence

i am using way point for the artificial car but i don't know the exact concept for that  i want to make 3 AI car so how can i mange them parameter based like acceleration speed rotation on turn and collision b/w them pl z guide me.

Comment: Your question needs to be more specific. Anyhow, the best way to learn is to experiment yourself. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what I want you to know what you want. Start by imaginging you are in the artificial intelligence engine. Where to go? What have you seen what you want? If you want to suggest that if you are in a position that wish a reality. Manage can be very hard on the eyes. Ensure that periodically interrupt the dream and drag on the work as long as possible at once.

Comment: Awesomely confusing sentence: To achieve what I want you to know what you want.

Comment: This is the most *awesome* question/answer pairing I have ever seen on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Neurofluxation, @debu: It seems to me, the two of you have not yet reached the level of spiritual transcendence required to understand this discussion.